# How to I pass a value from a child script to a parent script that are both running at the same time?

Tags: python, ipc

Return a value early to a calling process in Python?

Hello, I want to ask is there a way to have one script call another script, have both those scripts running at the same time, and have the child script send a value to the parent script long before that child script is done running (WITHOUT exiting that child script early)? I'm looking for a solution in Python, but any information or clues would help, thankyou.

I think one way to do this is to print the value that you want to send back to the parent script to the standard output and then have the the parent script redirect it or pick it up some how, but there must be a better solution, because what if the child script prints other things? (then the parent script has to know how to isolate that exact part of the output with something like Unix head and tail commands, and what if you don't want to use the standard output at all?)

I have searched for answers on this, but I cannot find any.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) to launch the child script from the parent script.
A [mp.Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) could be used to communicate output from the child script back to the parent. Here is a simple example:

**parent.py**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import child

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=child.main, args=(queue,))
    proc.daemon = True  
    # This launches the child process, calling child.main()
    proc.start()         
    for i in range(10):
        result = queue.get()  # Get results from child.main
        print(result)
```

**child.py**:

```
import time

def main(queue=None):
    for i in range(10):
        # do a computation
        result = i
        if queue:
            # Put a result in the queue for the parent to get
            queue.put(result)   
        time.sleep(.5)

if __name__=='__main__':  
    # We reach here only when child.py is run as a script 
    # (as opposed to child being imported as a module).
    main()
```

Note that the `result` passed through the `queue` must be picklable.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but now I am trying to figure out how does parent.py know to launch the child.py script instead of some other script?, because I don't see the name "child.py" mentioned anywhere in the "parent.py" script.

Comment: The parent.py script does not run the child.py script. Instead it just runs the one function `child.run`. But this is no real limitation since you can easily put all of a script's actions into a function. Some minor refactoring should allow you to run `child.py` as a standalone script and also import and call `child.run`. I'll edit my answer to (hopefully) clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to use the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) which is designed for exactly this purpose.